# Providing port number in MySQL or any other database

Tags: mysql, port

This question is related to other DBMS's as well, but I'll ask it as it relates to MySQL as that's the one I'm most familiar with. Why is it necessary to enter in the port name in a MySQL connection? I have never seen MySQL use any port other than `3306`, so to me entering in the port seems unnecessary (almost like typing in "http://google.com:80" in a web browser).

For example, from SequelPro:

[image]

Why is the port even included in the database connection? Is there ever a scenario where the port is **not** 3306 for mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run multiple instances of MySQL Server on the same host listening on the same IP interface, but they must be configured to use distinct ports.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-multi.html

Comment: I see. Have you come across that ever in real-world uses, or it's very rare?

Comment: It's uncommon, but I wouldn't say very rare. I have administered sites that used this method. It's more common to run just one mysqld per VM or Docker container on the same host, so each mysqld can still listen on port 3306 within its respective IP interface.

Comment: If we include testing environments, it's much more common to run mysqld instances side-by-side on the same host, and each mysqld uses a distinct port. You can run many mysqld instances for testing purposes with a product like https://github.com/datacharmer/dbdeployer

Answer (score 0):

It could be behind a TCP load balancer, that listens on 3306, and you want to connect to the real MySQL server directly.

There aren't many cases of this, but its probably better to leave the option (preferably with a 3306 default), than to omit it.

Comment: why would that be done rather than have MySQL directly listening at 3306? Would there be multiple MySQL servers behind the load balancer?